# div margin changing margin of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem which I don't know why it is happening. I have 2 div Wrappers, a so called "mainWrapper" which has an backround image and a child of this div called "loginWrapper".
I want the login Wrapper to be positioned 15% from top, but if i simply add the margin, it seems to also change the margin of the parent div (mainWrapper).

Can somebody explain to me why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

**Code:**

HTML:

```
<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="loginWrapper">
        <h:graphicImage id="logo" alt="spotted deluxe" url="resources/images/logo.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    background-color: green;
    background: url(../images/backround_red.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

div#mainWrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width:70em;
    height:100%;
    background: url(../images/header.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left:4em;
}

div#loginWrapper {
    /*margin-top: 15%;*/
}

img#logo {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it will add margin to parent. Try position instead.\

```
 div#mainWrapper {
   position: relative;
 }

div#loginWrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a special case of [margin collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). Some options to prevent it are:

1. Add 1px padding-top or border-top to the parent div
2. Make the parent div establish the new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (e.g. by adding to it overflow: hidden or changing its display to display: table)
3. Adding to the parent div the :before pseudo-element with display: table, as in the popular [Micro Clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).